# Superscript citations in order

Tags: citing, natbib

Is there any way to have superscript citations appear in numerical order in-text? Right now I'm citing sources and they're appearing in the order I've cited them.

This is what I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{fullpage}      
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{times}


\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {xxx} }
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}

\sectionfont{\normalsize}
\subsectionfont{\normalsize}

\begin{document} 

Text, citations

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{xxx}

\end{document}
```

So the in-text citation will read "blah blah^22,2,14,11" where I'd want it to read "blah blah^2,11,14,22". Is there something I need adjust or add to in order to have this work?

edit: added additional code--hope this helps with example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[super,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{xxx.bib}
@article{john,
    title={I am John},
    author={John Doe},
    year={2017}
}
@article{jane,
    title={I am Jane},
    author={Jane Doe},
    year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document} 

Text, \cite{john,jane}

\clearpage
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{xxx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My answer appears to have preceded yours by a minute or so.

Comment: Indeed, it did.

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the option `sort` (as well as `super`) while loading `natbib`:

```
\usepackage[super,sort]{natbib}
```

A full MWE (compile by running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reference.bib}
@misc{aaa, author = "AAA", title="111", year=3001}
@misc{bbb, author = "BBB", title="222", year=3002}
@misc{ccc, author = "CCC", title="333", year=3003}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[super,sort]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
zzz\cite{aaa,ccc,bbb}
\bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @frostfall - On this site, when two roughly equally good answers have been posted, the one that was posted first should be upvoted and/or accepted.